# Camera Calibration- Tsai's Algorithn javascript three.js implimentation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, camera, three.js, calibration

I'm trying to build a camera calibration function for a three.js app and could very much do with some help.

I have a geometry in a 3d scene, lets say for this example it is a cube. As this object and scene exist in 3d, all properties of the cube are known.

I also have a physical copy of the geometry.

What I would like to is take a photo of the physical geometry and mark 4+ points on the image in x and y. These points correspond to 4+ points in the 3d geometry.

Using these point correlations, I would like to be able to work out the orientation of the camera to the geometry in the photo and then match a virtual camera to the 3d geometry in the three.js scene.

I looked into the possibility of using an AR lib such as JS-aruco or JSARToolkit. But these systems need a marker, where as my system need to be marker less. The user will choose the 4 (or more) points on the image.

I've been doing some research and identified that Tsai's algorithm for camera alignment should suit my needs.

While I have a good knowledge of javascript and three.js, My linear algebra isn't the best and hence am having a problem translating the algorithm into javascript.

If anyone could give me some pointers, or is able to explain the process of Tsai's algorithm in a javascript mannor I would be so super ultra thankful.